# Angular append element onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want append this element on click:

```
<data-my-template/>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0"/>

  <title>Angular</title>
  <!-- CSS  -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>  
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<div id="line"></div>        

<button id="insert"> Insert </button>
<data-my-template/>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script> 
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**template.html**

```
<div class="row"> 
  <ul class="collection">
    <li class="collection-item avatar">
        <i class="material-icons circle">folder</i>
      <span class="title" ng-controller="name"> <b> {{ user.name + " " + user.surname }} </b></span>
      <p>First Line <br>
         Second Line
      </p>
      <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">grade</i></a>
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
// data

var name = "John";
var surname = "Doe";


// codes

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

  myApp.controller('name', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
      name: name,
      surname: surname
    };    
  }])

  myApp.directive('myTemplate', function() {
    return {      
      templateUrl: 'template.html'
    };
  });


// events

$('#insert').click(insert);

function insert(){

angular.element('#line').append("<div>TEST</div>");

angular.element('#line').append("<data-my-template/>");

}
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: It works: angular.element('#line').append("<div>TEST</div>");
It no works: angular.element('#line').append("<data-my-template/>");

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code as your solution:

**JS(app.js)**:

```
var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#line' ) );
myEl.append('Hi<br/>'); 
myEl.append('<data-my-template/>');
```

Above code will append `<data-my-template></data-my-template>` and result look like:

```
<div id="line">
    Hi<br>
    <data-my-template></data-my-template>
</div>
```

See my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/354mkqbp/)

Let me know if there is any query regarding this.

Comment: Thanks. But, <data-my-template> no works and not safe.

[ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Comment: Please see my JSFIDDLE, it works fine so it should work with your code. Please re-check  with my code. if `<data-my-template>`  not safe then why you try with this.?

Comment: only html, I can do so: 

angular.element('#line').append("Hi<br>");

You tried to Element? Does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The best I got was this:

**html**
    ...

```
<div id="line"></div>        

<button id="insert"> Insert </button>
...
```

**js**

```
...
$('#insert').click(insert);

function insert(){

    var $div = $('<data-my-template/>');

    $('#line').append($div);

    angular.element('#line').injector().invoke(function($compile) {
      var scope = angular.element($div).scope();
      $compile($div)(scope);
    });
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You close in your answer using the `$compile` service however all this jQuery for click handlers etc is not good.

First of all don't re-invent the wheel, angular has ways of adding a click handler for you (`ng-click`) second never manipulate the DOM in your controller, use a directive. (after all that's what all the different `ng-*` things are).

Anyhow to the question at had. Simply create a 'creator' directive. It is applied to an an element, will make use of the `$compile` service and add your content to the element its applied to. You can hard-code that content if you wish so you have a pair of `myTemplate` and `myTemplateCreator` directives. You you could make it generic and pass the content into it you want generating. For ease of use ive hard coded it.

So in it's entirety:

```
myApp.directive("add", function($compile){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        template: '<button ng-click="add()">Click to add buttons</button>',
        link: function ($scope, e, a) {
          var count = 0;
          $scope.add = function() {
            /*
                The single quotes around count are important. The count attribute is a scope variable.
                It is databound so what angular would do without the single quotes is look for a scope 
                variable called count to bind with. We don't want that we just want to pass it a single
                string value. Hence the extra single quotes.
            */
            var str = "<alert count=\"'" + count + "'\"></alert>";

            angular.element(e).append($compile(str)($scope));

            //Just so you can each add is different
            count += 1;
          }
        }
    }
});
```

What that will do is inject a button into the element its applied to. Every time that button is clicked it will inject a directive called alert into the same element and increment a counter. (The `alert` directive consumes that counter just so you can tell that each new `alert` directive is different)

You do not have to use a button to actually make the creation happen. This directive could listen to an event, so `$scope.$on()` it could expose a method that your controller calls, it could even put a watch on a scope variable.

Its important to note the `$compile` services also needs a scope that the created content will use. My `add` directive uses an inherited scope so the created content will have the same scope as the element the `add` directive was created on. This is also not set in stone.

[Compile Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) and 
[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/btpz8uya/1/)

Any questions or anything just ask.

Comment: I had seen this example. You tried with an element how of the question <data-my-template/>? Does not work.
I do not reinvented the wheel. I found this solution here: 

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector

And I used jQuery Click because is an event as any other. I could use php, haxe, flash (And I'll use). Anyway, thanks for the reply.

Comment: `my-template` is a directive. `alert` in my example was also a directive. I wasn't handing it to you on a plate so you can just copy and paste into your app but showing you how you could do it in a more 'angular' way rather than manually binding events and manipulating the DOM in your controller which is not a 'angular' way of working. You say using your own directive doesn't work. How doesn't it work?

Comment: Ok. I started learning angular today. More 20h I found out how to do this.
Or perhaps with Ember be better. What I want is to divide my application in modules. And do not rewrite code. Nor have a spaghetti javascript.